# Add suffix to variable value conditional on another variable

Tags: r, tidyverse

Given the data below, what is the easiest way to add a suffix to the variable 'var' depending on the value of 'type'? So for example, if type = "white", add "_t" to the end of each value of var, and add "_b" if type = "black".

```
structure(list(var = c("test", "test", "score", "score", "base", 
"base"), type = c("white", "black", "white", "black", "white", 
"black")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    var = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000024d0c9a2b10>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dplyr::case_when()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(var = case_when(type == "white" ~ paste0(var, "_t"),
                         type == "black" ~ paste0(var, "_b"))
         )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 2
#>   var     type 
#>   <chr>   <chr>
#> 1 test_t  white
#> 2 test_b  black
#> 3 score_t white
#> 4 score_b black
#> 5 base_t  white
#> 6 base_b  black
```

data from OP

```r
dat <- structure(list(var = c("test", "test", "score", "score", "base", 
                       "base"),
               type = c("white", "black", "white", "black", "white", 
                                         "black")),
          row.names = c(NA, -6L),
          class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(var = str_c(var, substr(str_replace(type, "^w", "t"), 1, 1), sep = '_'))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  var     type 
  <chr>   <chr>
1 test_t  white
2 test_b  black
3 score_t white
4 score_b black
5 base_t  white
6 base_b  black
```